# Generating the 3d graph in python is easy, but I can't seem to figure out how to display the 3d graph on the pdf

Tags: python, graph, 3d, matplotlib

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

data = [[1.3, 125, 0.0152093 ],
        [1.3, -40, 0.00864026],
        [3.6, 125, 0.0226226 ],
        [3.6, -40, 0.0221346 ],
        [5.5, 125, 0.0400638 ],
        [5.5, -40, 0.0417146 ],
        [1.1, 125, 0.053118  ],
        [1.65, 125, 0.0631874 ],
        [2.3, 125, 0.0828577 ]]


x, y, z = zip(*data)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x,y,z)
ax.set_title("Process: FF")
ax.set_xlabel('Voltage')
ax.set_ylabel('Temperature')
ax.set_zlabel('Power value')

#ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, z, rstride=10, cstride=10)

plt.show()
plt.savefig('example01.pdf')
```

Please help me to save the 3d graph in the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

From [the `savefig()` docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig),

```
plt.savefig('example01.pdf', format='pdf')
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

Switch the `plt.show()` and `plt.savefig(...)` line. `plt.show()` locks execution, and won't continue until you close the figure. And then when it tries to save the plot after you close it, it's already gone.

Alternatively you can try to save it through the plt.show dialog, then you can interactively rotate it to get the view you want.

```
plt.savefig('example01.pdf') 
plt.show()
```

Try calling `plt.show()` twice and see that nothing shows up the second time, to prove for yourself that this is the case.